# Drupal 7 - Why can't I create a single-page site?

Tags: drupal-7

I am in desperate need of help!

I spent all night yesterday trying to figure out why I can't get my site's content to align into a single-page format. I want you to be able to click on a menu link in my navigation bar and have the site automatically scroll down to the content that you selected through that link.

An example of how this works:

http://www.bootstrapzero.com/theme/landing-zero/

So, I followed this tutorial down to the letter:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvIuBIpfbbU

I tried using the "Single-Page Site" module for Drupal 7. But my content remained divided into separate pages, and even stranger, one of my menu links' content disappeared and the link brought me to my homepage.

I tried using the "Single-Page Website" module as well. This went even worse! My entire menu disappeared, and I had to spend a lot of time today trying to restore it.

I have two basic pages that I want to turn into a single-page. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Oh, and a potentially important note: I am using my Bootstrap-subtheme for my website.

Thank you so much, guys!

Answer (score 1):

on drupal 7 there is a bootstrap subtheme called barrio that looks into the single page layout 
https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio
follow the instruction and install the needed module (especially the void menu)

another way could be to use panel and panel page, create a panel page layout with one single columne, add your two nodes on the panel page, set it as home page and you should be golden.
D7 do not allow menu pointing to same page anchor (#div-name) unless you install the void menu module

also, idk if that is what you need , but you might want to take a look at this one 
http://cmsbots.com/drupal-7-theme-generator

Comment: You're awesome, man. I really appreciate this, I think it will help!